# Easiest way to Increase by one the actual string value

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that i need to match with another array of string. If I found matches with the both array values then I have to split the numerical value from the string, and add *1* with that numerical value and append with the actual string with the new value. I tried in some splitting and concatenation. But I didn't get the proper and efficient way to solve the problem. Below is my scenario.

**Actual Strings:**

```
BK-TS00023,X1-TS00000101,X4-A10000024,Y1-3,
```

**Comparision String**

```
BK Books      // Compare first two characters => BK Books matches with BK-TS00023
X1 Serials    // Compare first two characters => X1 Serials matches with X1-TS00000101
```

So, When I found the match with those strings, I need to get the numerical values like **00023**, **00000101** and increase the value by 1. Then append with default string. The resultant string will be something like this.

**Result String**

```
'BK-TS00024',
'X1-TS00000102',
'X4-A10000025',
'Y1-4'
```

I tried the below way. Please anyone help me to provide the proper way to do this scenario.

**Code**

```
InfoType="BK Books"; // or "X1 Serials" // or etc ..
var splitInfo = InfoType.Split(' ');
        var SiteFileInfo = Db.SiteFiles.Where(asd => asd.Code == "AutoBarcode").Select(asd => asd.Line1).FirstOrDefault();
        var splitSiteFile = SiteFileInfo.Split(',');
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (var s in splitSiteFile)
        {
            cnt += 1;
            if (s.Contains(splitInfo[0]))
            {

                //var infoSiteSplit = s.Split('-');
                var olyNumber = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{N})");
                int i = 0;
                string Truncstring = "";
                foreach (var a in olyNumber)
                {
                    bool result = int.TryParse(a, out i);
                    if (result)
                    {
                        i += 1;
                        int befconv = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                        Truncstring = s.Replace(befconv.ToString(), i.ToString());
                    }
                }
                splitSiteFile[cnt - 1] = Truncstring;
                string JoinString = string.Join(",", splitSiteFile);
                Db.ExecuteStoreCommand("update SiteFile set Line1={0} where Code={1}", JoinString, "AutoBarcode");
                Db.SaveChanges();
                return Truncstring;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is your expected output here? 'BK-TS00024 X1-TS00000102'?

Comment: Its a two strings ..'BK-TS00024', 'X1-TS00000102' .. Please see updated code also.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) (and optionally, delegates instead of `MatchEvaluator` instances).

Try this (it will increase with 1 all matches in the filter):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "BK-TS00023,X1-TS00000101,X4-A10000024,Y1-3,";
        var filter = new[] { "BK Books", "X1 Serials" };
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        var result = IncreaseWithFilter(input, filter);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static string IncreaseWithFilter(
        string input,
        IEnumerable<string> filter)
    {
        var truncatedFilter = filter.Select(f => f.Substring(0, 2));
        var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"([^,].*?)\d+(?=,)",
            (match1) =>
            {
                var value = match1.Value;
                if (truncatedFilter.Any(f => match1.Value.StartsWith(f)))
                {
                    value = Regex.Replace(match1.Value, @"(?<=)\d+",
                        (match2) =>
                        {
                            return (Convert.ToInt32(match2.Value) + 1)
                                .ToString()
                                .PadLeft(match2.Value.Length, '0');
                        });
                }
                return value;
            });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BK-TS00023,X1-TS00000101,X4-A10000024,Y1-3,
BK-TS00024,X1-TS00000102,X4-A10000024,Y1-3,
```

Sample usage in your code:

```
InfoType = "BK Books";
var SiteFileInfo = Db.SiteFiles
    .Where(asd => asd.Code == "AutoBarcode")
    .Select(asd => asd.Line1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var result = IncreaseWithFilter(
    SiteFileInfo, 
    new[] { InfoType });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply take the right part (the number part) of the string, convert it to int, increase it and convert to string again?

Something like:

```
public string IncreaseByOne(string original) {
  var numberpart = "";
  var index = original.Length - 1;
  while (index != 0) {
    var oneletter = original.Substring(index, 1);
    var isint = int.TryParse(oneletter, out digit);
    if (!isint) break;
    numberpart += oneletter;
    --index;
  }
  var firstpart = original.Substring(0, orignal.Length - numberpart.Length);
  var padlength = numberpart.Length;
  int value;
  int.TryParse(numberpart, out value);
  var result = ++value.ToString().PadLeft(padlength, '0');
  return firstpart + result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an extra tip that could simplify the string creation after increasing the int, instead of calculating the length of the string and do PadLeft with zero's, you can also take an int and use StringFormat IFormatProvider to add the leading zero's:

```
string paddedString = String.Format("TS{1:00000}", count); 
//when count = 24, should output "TS00024"
```